# React Native - com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMergeFailureException

Tags: xml, react-native

Hi i'm upgrading the sdk to the latest one (react-native 0.73.6) and changing the file based on the react-native upgrade helper. However, when i tried to run the project, it shows this error and i couldn't found any solution in google. Below is the error and my code.

Error
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with
an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'. > com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing D:\PROJECT\PROJECT_NAME\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <!-- <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="true"/> -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />  
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

https://github.com/vigidroid/fat-aar-plugin/issues/2

What i can google is this issues but the issues seems like not related to mine